# How to pass exception explicitly to the main thread in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am familiar with the fact that exception thrown in a thread normally couldn't be caught in another thread.
How can i transfer the error however to the main thread?

```
public static void Main()
{
   new Thread (Go).Start();
}

static void Go()
{
  try
  {
    // ...
    throw null;    // The NullReferenceException will get caught below
    // ...
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // Typically log the exception, and/or signal another thread
    // that we've come unstuck
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4 there are better ways to do this with `Tasks`, but assuming you need to use `Threads`...

If your example is a console app, then your Main method will exit, possibly before `Go` starts executing. So your "main thread" may not exist when the exception is thrown. To stop this, you need some synchronization.

Something like this should do:

```
static Exception _ThreadException = null;

public static void Main()
{
    var t = new Thread ( Go );
    t.Start();

    // this blocks this thread until the worker thread completes
    t.Join();

    // now see if there was an exception
    if ( _ThreadException != null ) HandleException( _ThreadException );
}

static void HandleException( Exception ex )
{
    // this will be run on the main thread
}

static void Go()
{
    try
    {
        // ...
        throw null;    // The NullReferenceException will get caught below
        // ...
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        _ThreadException = ex;
    }
}
```

If this is a UI app, things are a bit easier. You will need to pass some reference to your UI thread into the `Go` method so it knows where to send the exception. The best way to do this is to pass the `SynchronizationContext` of the UI thread.

Something like this would work:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var ui = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    new Thread ( () => Go( ui ) ).Start();
}

static void HandleException( Exception ex )
{
    // this will be run on the UI thread
}

static void Go( SynchronizationContext ui )
{
    try
    {
        // ...
        throw null;    // The NullReferenceException will get caught below
        // ...
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        ui.Send( state => HandleException( ex ), null );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If C# 4.0 is available to you, then you can use a `Task` instead of a `Thread`. Uncaught exceptions in the `Task` are automatically propagated to the joining thread. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415.aspx for examples and exceptions to this rule.

Answer (score 3):

This is a really old thread but I have an original approach to this issue so I will put my solution here.

The main goal in my case was that the main thread will be interrupted by exception at the moment that the child thread got the exception, instead of monitoring or waiting as proposed in other answers. 
As have been said in other threads, we can't do that with conventional way but we can send interrupt from the other thread to the main thread.

Sending interrupt to the main thread generates ThreadInterruptedException on the main thread. So catching it in the main thread and checking any flag raised by the other thread will do the exception details transferring as well.

Here is a minimal example (you can break it to classes and do better design later)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        // initialize the second thread ***************************
        Exception exFromThread = null;

        Thread thread = new Thread((mainThread) =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            exFromThread = new Exception("Exception from other thread");
            ((Thread)mainThread).Interrupt(); // makes the main thread get exception
        });

        thread.Start(Thread.CurrentThread);
        // ********************************************************

        try
        {
            // This loop represents your main thread logic
            for (int i = 0; true; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                Console.WriteLine("main thread logic: " + i);
            }
        }
        catch (ThreadInterruptedException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread have been interrupted");
            Console.WriteLine(exFromThread.Message);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key..");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe to general [unhandled exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) at the app level.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your so called "main thread" should poll or wait for exceptions. This can be done with a queue and a semaphore.

```
catch( Exception ex )
{
   lock( queueLock )
   {
      queue.Enqueue( ex )
      semaphore.Release();
   }

}
```

In your main thread you can poll or wait for the semaphore.